# Jenkins Pipeline-How to use release plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to use Jenkins release plugin in my job.
I am able to config Jenkins release in any job without Jenkins pipeline.
With Jenkins pipeline as this build environment Tab is missing, how to configure release in Jenkins file?

[image: Release configuration section without pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [release step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/release/) in your Jenkins file.

Comment: These steps are for triggering release job and not for configuring release.